# what is the 'self.__class__.__missing__' mean 

Tags: python, pinax

in pinax Userdict.py:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.data:
            return self.data[key]
        if hasattr(self.__class__, "__missing__"):
            return self.__class__.__missing__(self, key)
```

why does it do this on `self.__class__.__missing__`.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UserDict.py presented [here](http://www.manifestdensity.net/2009/05/05/python_on_the_fonera/UserDict.py) emulates built-in `dict` closely, so for example:

```
>>> class m(dict):
...   def __missing__(self, key): return key + key
... 
>>> a=m()
>>> a['ciao']
'ciaociao'
```

just as you can override the special method `__missing__` to deal with missing keys when you subclass the built-in `dict`, so can you override it when you subclass that `UserDict`.

The official Python docs for dict are [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__missing__#mapping-types-dict), and they do say:

> New in version 2.5: If a subclass of
>   dict defines a method `__missing__`(),
>   if the key key is not present, the
>   `d[key]` operation calls that method
>   with the key key as argument. The
>   `d[key]` operation then returns or
>   raises whatever is returned or raised
>   by the `__missing__(key)` call if the
>   key is not present. No other
>   operations or methods invoke
>   `__missing__()`. If `__missing__()` is not defined, `KeyError` is raised.
>   `__missing__()` must be a method; it cannot be an instance variable. For an
>   example, see `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **use default values in a dict** (aka *__missing__*), you can check out [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from  collections module:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(int)

a[1] # -> 0
a[2] += 1
a # -> defaultdict(int, {1: 0, 2: 1})
```